# Is it possible to write a system of equations with variables in order when coefficients are not numeric

Tags: pdftex

I am writing an assignment on systems of linear equations with variables x, y, z. I want students to determine a coefficient k which give i) a unique solution, ii) no solution, and iii) more than one solution. I want all equations in a system to go in the order x+y+z=constant. Instead I get the system as in my mwe below.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \geometry{
a4paper,
total={210mm,297mm},
left=18mm,
right=15mm,
top=18mm,
bottom=18mm,
}
\begin{document}
Determine values of k such that the systems in unknowns x,y and z has \begin{inparaenum}[a)] \item a unique solution, \item no solution, \item more than one solution.\\
\end{inparaenum}
\begin{inparaenum}[i)]
\item
\systeme{kx+y+z=1,x+ky+z=1,x+y+kz=1} \hspace{5pt}
\item
\systeme{x+2y+kz=1,2x+ky+8z=3} \hspace{5pt}
\item
\systeme{x+y+kz=2,3x+4y+2z=k,2x+3y-z=1}
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

Is what am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can tell `\systeme` what letters are to be considered as unknowns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\systeme[xyz]{kx+y+z=1,x+ky+z=1,x+y+kz=1}

\medskip

\systeme[xyz]{x+2y+kz=1,2x+ky+8z=3}

\medskip

\systeme[xyz]{x+y+kz=2,3x+4y+2z=k,2x+3y-z=1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much @egreg. You have sorted out my problem, thanks for your time.